# How do I style or remove PrimeNG p-table gridlines?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to remove or, at least, change the color of p-table gridlines.

I've tried inspecting the code on browser to see if I can find the element creating those lines but I couldn't find it.

I tried applying styles to td and tr but couldn't remove the gridlines.

Here's a link to the image showing the gridlines: [The gridlines I'm trying to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsVPC.png)

Using:
Angular 11
PrimeNG 11

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNg applies border to `td` or `tr`. One reason why your stylings are not applied is because of **CSS specificity**

> If there are two or more CSS rules that point to the same element, the selector with the highest specificity value will "win", and its style declaration will be applied to that HTML element.

Source: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)

To change the gridlines, you need to target td/tr. Add these styles in the global `styles.scss`/`styles.css` file using:

```
.p-datatable.p-datatable-gridlines .p-datatable-tbody > tr > td{
    border:unset;
   // border-width:0; This will also work
}
```

***Note:** Its important to add these styles to global styles file because Angular encapsulates the styles of a component by default(unless you set `ViewEncapsulation:none`). If added to a particular component, your styles may end up like:

```
.p-datatable.p-datatable-gridlines[_ngcontent-mqq-c93]   .p-datatable-tbody[_ngcontent-mqq-c93]    > tr[_ngcontent-mqq-c93]    > td[_ngcontent-mqq-c93] {
```

If it still doesn't solve your problem, take a look at `p-datatable-gridlines`. Based upon your selected PrimeNg theme, try to add specific CSS selectors by inspecting the element & identifying current selectors that targets td/tr.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v11-lts/#/table/gridlines

Comment: I couldn't make it work. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) pseudo-class in your CSS to penetrate the view encapsulation of `p-table`:

```css
:host ::ng-deep .p-datatable .p-datatable-tbody > tr > td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Be sure to combine it with `:host`, though: `:host ::ng-deep`. That will scope the style to your component, otherwise the style will be global.

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-eafqej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css) where I removed the grid lines via `app.component.css`.

Comment: I tried this on both app.component.css and the specific component the table is in and it didn't work.. Maybe it's the theme I chose.
I can't even find the rule to the element creating those gridlines (on browser inspector). It seems the lines are there but nothing created them..
Thanks anyway..

Comment: @Renato if you could put together a StackBlitz or something that demonstrates the issue, it would make it easier for others to help troubleshoot. On the `p-table` in my StackBlitz, the lines were just bottom borders on the `td` elements, but maybe your scenario is different?

Comment: I don't have permission to post the code. And the existence of gridlines are not something relevant, so we've decided to ignore them. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
:host ::ng-deep .p-datatable .p-datatable-tbody > tr > td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```